# Two objects in namespace to be default initialized by different functions and used by class within namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, window, ncurses

I have a strange request. I have a namespace foo with two declared objects of type `bar`, namely `bar1` and `bar2`, which I would like to initialize via constructor of class bar. Is this a sound way to do so:

```
namespace foo {
    class bar;
    foo::bar *bar1;
    foo::bar *bar2;
}

class foo::bar
{
    /* Initialize bar1 and bar2 in the constructor.
     */
    InitializeBar();
};
```

The reason behind this shenanigan is I would like to create an object similar to `cout` and `cin` such that `foo::bar1` and `foo::bar2` need not be defined by the user. More specifically, I am using `ncurses` and wish to replace `cout` with an output window `bar1` and `cin` with an input window `bar2` and overload the operators and such that `foo::bar1 << a prints` a in the output window as I see fit and `foo::bar2 >> b` extracts the values from the input window and dumps it into b. I am able to do this via the C functions call but I need help to extend it to C++. Perhaps default initialization of `bar1` and `bar2` accordingly?

Comment: What if you have multiple bar objects, `bar1` and `bar2` will be "initialized" more than once?

Comment: @EricZ no, I want them to be initialized exactly once, that too in secret. The user will never call a constructor, only use these two objects, similar to how cout and cin of iostream are used.

Comment: You can use the factory pattern then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the simple function pattern. You keep the constructor as private and the clients can only access these objects via two get functions. You probably want to disable the copy constructor and copy assignment operator as well.

```
// .h
namespace foo
{
   class bar: boost noncopyable
   {
   public:
      static bar* getInputWindow()
      {
         static bar s_input;
         return &s_input;
      }
      static bar* getOutputWindow()
      {
         static bar s_output;
         return &s_output;
      }

   private:
      bar()
      {
      }
   };

   // global/namespace objects clients should directly use
   extern bar *input;
   extern bar *output;
}

// .cpp
namespace foo
{
   bar *input = bar::getInputWindow();
   bar *output = bar::getOutputWindow();
}
```

Comment: I never thought about singleton patterns before. One thing should be clarified: never define namespace variables within a header file, only within a source file. I've edited your example to make this clear to future readers because I wasted too much time on it. Really cool code, will adapt the singleton pattern more often.

Comment: Sure, accepted your edit. Be aware that this is not the singleton pattern. Singleton pattern refers to a scenario where a class can only be instantiated once. But in your case it's not. To me, it's more like the factory pattern.